# CMake get list of files to be signed

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm trying to make a .msi installation package using CMake, CPack, and Wix. The issue is I'm trying to sign the executables and DLLs that are going to be installed.

Currently I am trying to use a custom cmake script by setting CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPTS
`SET( CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/signcert.cmake")`

And inside signcert.cmake is where I run into issue. I want to use signtool to sign:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND cmd /c signtool sign /debug /v /sm /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /sha1 ${THUMBPRINT} "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}applications/bin/*"
)
```

The signtool command execute properly when done in a VS Command Console (vcvarsall.bat), however the wild card does not expand properly in the execute_process, it says cannot find *.

How can I find a list of files in a particular directory and store it in a CMake variable? For example ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}applications/bin/* ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely caused by the fact that your `signcert.cmake` script will not know the path for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. It is not forwarded from the main CMake invocation.

To get around this, you can make a script template `signcert.cmake.in`, and use [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/configure_file.html) to insert the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` path into your script.

Within your script, one option to more safely obtain and pass a list of files is to use [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/file.html#glob) to get a list of files in the directory, before calling `execute_process`. Here's what your script could look like (note the `@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@` marked for variable substitution):

```
file(GLOB MY_FILES_TO_SIGN
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@applications/bin/*)

# Pass MY_FILES_TO_SIGN variable to execute_process.
execute_process(
    COMMAND cmd /c signtool sign /debug /v /sm /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com /td sha256 /sha1 ${THUMBPRINT} ${MY_FILES_TO_SIGN}
)
```

In your main CMake project, configure this file using the following, which will generate `signcert.cmake` with the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` substituted inside:

```
configure_file(signcert.cmake.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/signcert.cmake @ONLY)
```

Comment: Hi there! I don't know why, but file(GLOB ...) does not work in CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPTS

I did this, but did not see any files (files are definitely there)

file(GLOB MY_FILES_TO_SIGN
     LIST_DIRECTORIES false
     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}applications/bin/*)
message(FATAL_ERROR ${MY_FILES_TO_SIGN} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}applications/bin/)

Comment: @MistaZ Ah that's correct, the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable won't transfer from the primary CMake invocation, but you can substitute that path into your script before its used.  See my updated response.